# Динамическое наполнение страницы (всеми участниками) через @Singleton

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, singleton

Хочу добавить на стартовую страницу таблицу со списком который сможет динамически наполнять каждый участник этого сайта но при той реализации которую делаю это невыполнимо по причине того что при добавлении новой записи прежняя затирается, далее код:

JSF:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" >
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:form prependId="false" id="form"> 
                <h:selectOneListbox>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{singleMeesage.messages}" id="singleItems"/>
                </h:selectOneListbox> 
            </h:form>
            <h:form>
               <h:panelGroup>
                     <br />
                     <h:outputText value="message"/> <br /> 
                     <h:inputText value="#{singleMeesage.messag}" /> <br />
                     <h:commandButton value="добавить" id="submit"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup> 
    </h:body>
</html>
```

далее EJB:

```
package message;      

import java.util.ArrayList;      
import java.util.List;      
import javax.ejb.Singleton;      
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;        

@Singleton       
@ManagedBean      
public class SingleMeesage {       
    private List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();       
    private List<String> names;      

    private String messag;      

    public String getMessag() {    
        return messag;    
    }    

    public void setMessag(String messag) {      
        messages.add(messag);     
        this.messag = messag;    
    }    

    public List<String> getMessages(){    
        return messages;     
    }    
}
```

Преследую цель общедоступного контента (редактируемого) для всех участников

Comment: а вы базу не используете?

Comment: Будет очень затратно...я хочу вызывать добавление в базу только один раз в  3 часа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в аннотациях компонента `SingleMeesage`. Аннотация `@ManagedBean` сообщает о том, что к компоненту можно обращаться из `JSF`-страниц. При этом в `Javadocs` к классу указано следующее:

> The scope of the managed bean is declared using one of NoneScoped,
>   RequestScoped, ViewScoped, SessionScoped, ApplicationScoped, or
>   CustomScoped annotations. **If the scope annotations are omitted, the
>   bean must be handled as if the RequestScoped annotation is present**.

Т.е., ваш компонент считается `RequestScoped`, т.к. ни одна из упомянутых аннотаций не присутствует в определении класса. Это приводит к тому, что состояние списка `messages` не сохраняется между обращениями к компоненту. Для решения вашей задачи, определение компонента должно быть таким:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
public class SingleMeesage {
}
```

Аннотация `javax.ejb.Singleton` игнорируется на уровне `JSF`, т.е., в данном случае ни на что не влияет. Она используется для создания компонентов, управляемых контейнером (сервером приложений), например, неких сервисов, запускаемых по расписанию.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам.

Answer (score -2):

Проблема решается через статический список

Comment: Можете подробнее описать как решили проблему? Привести примеры кода?